# Can a Flink job manager have/controll multiple task manager's cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

Could you please let me know if we can control the multiple task manager's cluster by one Job manager? My idea is to have multiple flink cluster per job wise and manage them by only one Job manager to save resources of JM.

Comment: What do You mean by multiple Clusters per job ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to run each flink jobs on separate cluster so one cluster for one job(small cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Every cluster needs its own Job Manager. You can, however, have a session cluster that runs multiple jobs concurrently. And you can use [fine-grained resource management](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/finegrained_resource/#fine-grained-resource-management) to fine-tune the task managers.